# how to add multiple roles to an admin user in Apache tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat

Recently i've installed an apache tomcat 8.
my tomcat-users.xml contains this:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="pass1234" roles="admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I want to enable openning manager app and server status on this user too.
can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the appropriate roles (see [the documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html) for the full list), and add them to the user's `roles` attribute, using a comma as the separator:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="pass1234" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-status"/>
</tomcat-users>
```